# std::unique_ptr test before taking ownership

Tags: c++, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I have a class which is basically a queue used to transfer dynamically allocated objects between 2 threads. The first thread creates the objects and the second one consumes them. I use `std::unique_ptr` to pass the objects ownership from thread 1 to thread 2.

Actually calls to the method that put the objects into the queue is like this:

```
queue.put(std::move(unique_ptr_to_my_object));
```

and the signature:

```
bool Queue::put(std::unique_ptr<T> p);
```

The problem is the `put()` method has to check some condition to decide if the object could be added to the queue. In case the condition is false the method simply returns false to indicate it can't add the object to the queue, but the object is destroyed because ownership has already be taken by `put()`.

So I wanted to know if it's ok to rewrite `put()` like this or if there is a better solution:

```
bool Queue::put(std::unique_ptr<T> &ref) {
    if(CANNOT_ADD)
        return false; // ownership remains in the calling function
    std::unique_ptr<T> p = std::move(ref); // we know we can add so take ownership
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I would change the revised function to `Queue::put(std::unique_ptr<T>&& ref)`.

Comment: @Tyker No it doesn't.  It takes a reference to an rvalue.  It's not until you use it to assign or initialize something that it actually is moved.  Remember, only a move constructor or move assignment operator actually moves something.

Comment: @NathanOliver Still why?  In this case you probably *do* want to restrict to an l-value reference ... otherwise there's only a temporary left holding the baby if the put fails.

Comment: @MartinBonner Why limit the function to only lvalues?  If I get a `unique_ptr` from some function and don't really care if it is moved into the queue or not why do I need to make it lvalue first.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well it obviously depends on the overall requirements, but usually these sorts of things are not completely general purpose.  Given that the OP was concerned about losing the object if the `put` fails, I imagine the proposed usage is that one where you *should* care if it moved into the queue - if it fails, you have to do something else instead.  I agree though, if  one only *sometimes* care about the object, then your approach makes sense.

Comment: @James I think your original solution is actually the best one.  Returning the object in case of failure is counter-intuitive and uses inverted logic (it effectively returns false for success and true for failure).  The only change I would make is to rename the method `tryPut` so that it's clear at a glance that it can fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  The alternative would be:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> Queue::put(std::unique_ptr<T> p) {
    if (CANNOT_ADD)
        return p; // Ownership returned to caller.
    /* ... */
    return {}; // Return empty nullptr to indicate success.
}
```

Your way has the advantage that the caller retains ownership if the code in `...` throws.

Comment: I think, it is better this way, because there is no conditional taking ownership, which is kinda painful.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes that was my thought too, but it really depends on what problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: The trouble I see is that the user of `put()` can still use it incorrectly. If they call `put()` and don't do anything with the result then objects are silently deleted when the condition fails. I prefer the pass by reference. The owner retains ownership unless the `put()` explicitly accepts it.

Answer (score 3):

You can change signature of the function to:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> Queue::put(std::unique_ptr<T> p);
```

so if that function cannot take that object it would return that pointer back, or `nullptr` otherwise. Another solution is to take ownership conditionally:

```
bool Queue::put(std::unique_ptr<T> &&p);
```

and move out object only in success. Accepting rvalue reference vs lvalue one is better in this case due to at least 2 reasons:

1. You can still pass temporary.
2. You need to use `std::move` explicitly in calling code.

Though the fact that you can use that pointer after `std::move` make this variant is less readable.